# How can I update an element property using simple_html_dom

Tags: php, dom

Id like to update the 'src' attribute of an img tag using Simple HTML DOM. Ive got his at the top of the php file (join.php) which contains the img file:

```
include_once("simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php");
$htmldomOb = file_get_html('join.php');
$htmldomOb->find('img[id=imgtapchat]', 0)->src = './tapchat/clss_tapcht-1.php';
echo $htmldomOb;
```

This works but outputs the entire page again since i read in the entire page dom object. How can i just update the image src similar to how it is done in jQuery - As it says in the SimpleHTMLDOM site docs

> Find tags on an HTML page with selectors just like jQuery

With thanks

Comment: I don't get it - are you trying to *output* just the <img> tag on the last line? Your question is confusing, because you are *updating* only the <img id="imgtapchat"> src attribute. However, when you execute the "echo" statement on the last line, you are providing it with the entire HTML DOM for the file you loaded. That is exactly how that works. I think if you wanted to output just the <img> tag, you could do: `echo $htmldomOb->find('#imgtapchat');` ... (For what it's worth, you would store that in a variable since you're using it more than once.)

Comment: Yes thats exactly whats happening im outputting the entire html dom (when i right-click and view source) i can see the entire html source again, though the image src IS updated correctly. As you state i just want to modify the image src. I know i need to have a DOM object  to work with i just dont want to output it again after the operation.

Comment: That does not answer my question - what do you expect the final line to output (i.e., what is your target scenario)? Do you just want it to output the `<img>` tag with an updated `src`?

Comment: Yes, i dont want anything else on the page to change other than the updated target image source attribute. My code is featured above the opening html tag as usual with php so that i can make modifications to the page via php before the page is visible. If you can image in jQuery you simply target the image src and change it, this is what i want to do here

Comment: I think you have fundamentally misunderstood the difference between executing code on the server and executing code on the client (the user's web browser). PHP is server code. Either you swap out the img src before the page is sent to the user's browser at all, or you change just the attribute using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I use PHP Dom extension to rewrite PHP Simple Dom, just finished. You can try it here.
http://shinbonlin.github.io/html-parser/

Comment: Thanks -  looks interesting - but will give similar result to SimpleHTMLDOM. My goal is to hide the images' src url from casual viewing with 'view source' right clicking in browsers. The only way i can see of achieving this is with jQuery since i can make the assgnment in an external .js file, leaving the 'images src attribute blank in the html markup (though leaving img src blank in html is not good practice). Obviously its a comprimise since the .js file is easily findable in any browsers developer tools.

Comment: Once the image is loaded, people can still see where it came from. I don't see the point other than as security theater (ergo, not real security). At any rate, you would probably need to first load the page with no src values and then yes, add them with JS after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thats excactly what ive explained above (did you read it first?) - the address isnt viewable in the source tag once loaded since its assigned as a target via jQuery  - 'viewing the code' in the browser will still show an empty src attribute and will always show an empty src. The point i'm making is that the jquery external file with the jquery is easily found by more web savvy users than the usual casual web visitor.